# map world coordinate to a texture's value in fragment shader

Tags: canvas, three.js, glsl, webgl, texture2d

I am trying to map a world coordinate to a texture's value in the fragment shader using threeJS.

The generated 'color' is only black but webgl doesn't return any error.

Here is what I get:

- in the 3D, what I get in webgl (black slice instead of an image)
- in the 2D canvas, what I should in webgl.

[image]

My shaders:

```
<script id="vertShader" type="shader">

varying vec4 vPos;

void main() {
    vPos = modelViewMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0 );
    gl_Position = projectionMatrix *
                  modelViewMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0 );
}
</script>

<script id="fragShader" type="shader">

uniform mat4 rastoijk;
uniform sampler2D ijk;
uniform vec3 dimensionsIJK;

varying vec4 vPos;

void main(void) {
    // get IJK coordinates of current element
    vec4 ijkPos = rastoijk * vPos;
    //convert IJK coordinates to texture coordinates
    float sliceIndex = float(ijkPos[2])*(float(dimensionsIJK[0])*float(4))*float(dimensionsIJK[1]);
    float rowIndex = ijkPos[1]*(dimensionsIJK[0]*float(4));
    float colIndex = ijkPos[0]*float(4);
    vec2 textureCoordinates = vec2(colIndex, sliceIndex + rowIndex);
    vec3 color = texture2D( ijk, textureCoordinates ).rgb;

    gl_FragColor = vec4(color, 1.0);
  }
</script>
```

and the relevant part of the threeJS part:

```
  var mat = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
        uniforms: {
            ijk: {type: 't', value: ijkRGBATex},
            dimensionsIJK: {type: 'v3', value: new THREE.Vector3( dimensions[0], dimensions[1], dimensions[2] )},
            rastoijk: {type: 'm4', value: new THREE.Matrix4().set(rasijk[0], rasijk[4], rasijk[8], rasijk[12],
                                         rasijk[1], rasijk[5], rasijk[9], rasijk[13],
                                         rasijk[2], rasijk[6], rasijk[10], rasijk[14],
                                         rasijk[3], rasijk[7], rasijk[11], rasijk[15])}
        },
        vertexShader: document.
                      getElementById('vertShader').text,
        fragmentShader: document.
                      getElementById('fragShader').text
    });
```

and my IJK texture is generated as below:

```
ijkRGBATex = new THREE.DataTexture( _imageRGBA, _dims[0].length * 4, _dims[1]*_dims[2], THREE.RGBAFormat );
```

where:

```
var _dims = [numberCols, numberRows, numberSlices];
var _imageRGBA = new Float32Array(_dims[2] *_dims[1] * _dims[0] * 4);
  for(var i=0; i<_data.length; i++){
    _imageRGBA[4*i] = _imageRGBA[4*i + 1] = _imageRGBA[4*i + 2] = ((_data[i] - _min) / (_max - _min));
    _imageRGBA[4*i + 3] = 1;
  }
```

Does what I try to do make sense at all? I don't expect to have it correct there but I do not see any white pixels in my texture, which is the most problematic.

Best,

Comment: I know it's kinda of a lazy answer, but have checked if the sampler is being correctly bound? You could try to use another texture or a fixed texture coord. that could possibly return you a non-black value (i.e.: 0.5).

Comment: yes you are right, the issue is that the way I generate the texture must be in correct, but still not luck (see edits)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28188775/generate-texture-from-array-in-threejs

Answer (score 0):

issue is that the texture we are trying to display is not valid. New thread create about this specific issue: [generate texture from array in threejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28188775/generate-texture-from-array-in-threejs)