# generate texture from array in threejs

Tags: javascript, three.js, texture2d

I am trying to generate a texture from an array in threeJS and it is not working as expected.

It appears that the way I generate the texture is not correct.

If I use the following texture, it works as expected.
http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/demos/assets/crate.jpg

`crateTex = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('data/crate.jpg');`

[image]

If I generate a dummy texture and try to display it, it is all black...

```
var dummyRGBA = new Uint8Array(4 * 4 * 4);
for(var i=0; i< 4 * 4; i++){
  // RGB from 0 to 255
  dummyRGBA[4*i] = dummyRGBA[4*i + 1] = dummyRGBA[4*i + 2] = 255*i/(4*4);
  // OPACITY
  dummyRGBA[4*i + 3] = 255;
}

dummyDataTex = new THREE.DataTexture( dummyRGBA, 4, 4, THREE.RGBAFormat );
dummyDataTex.needsUpdate = true;

dummyTex = new THREE.Texture(dummyDataTex);
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your mistake is in the fact that you make a texture of a texture.

When you do:

```
dummyDataTex = new THREE.DataTexture( dummyRGBA, 4, 4, THREE.RGBAFormat );
```

the object `dummyDataTex` that you create here is already of type `THREE.Texture`.

So your next step:

```
dummyTex = new THREE.Texture(dummyDataTex);
```

is not necessary. You should instead immediately use `dummyDataTex`.

Comment: Thanks that fixed it. Next issue is that my "real" texture is too big to be passed (256*256*256*4) so I guess I'll have to find some work around. Does it make sense to attach 256 textures of 256*256*4 to the shader? Thanks anyway

Comment: I wouldn't know. Not that much experience with textures :)